# Package Installer crash Android 2.3.5

Tags: android, installation, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am developing an application for minSdkVersion = 7 and targetSdkVersion = 14. and it crashes the package installer of the phone. The phone is running on Android 2.3.5.

"Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped."

Attached are the logs that i receive on crash. I also tried with reducing apk size to just 630kb and my device have 60 MB free phone storage for apps, But it still giving some memory issues.

```
08-03 15:21:32.308: W/dalvikvm(2455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=7367KB, Allocated=3168KB, Bitmap Size=10628KB)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:481)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1727)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:590)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getAppSnippet(PackageUtil.java:179)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress.initView(InstallAppProgress.java:192)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppProgress.onCreate(InstallAppProgress.java:132)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-03 15:21:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2455):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 15:21:32.328: W/ActivityManager(126):   Force finishing activity com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress
08-03 15:21:32.829: W/ActivityManager(126): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{409e1908 com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress}
08-03 15:21:33.509: D/dalvikvm(126): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1972K, 35% free 8528K/12935K, external 3813K/4538K, paused 6ms+35ms
08-03 15:21:34.581: D/dalvikvm(126): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1906K, 33% free 8669K/12935K, external 3805K/4538K, paused 6ms+10ms
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126): Error running process
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/xbin/procrank] Working Directory: null Environment: [ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=10, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/com.htc.commonctrl.jar:/system/framework/com.htc.framework.jar:/system/framework/com.htc.android.pimlib.jar:/system/framework/com.htc.android.easopen.jar:/system/framework/com.scalado.util.ScaladoUtil.jar:/system/framework/com.orange.authentication.simcard.jar:/system/framework/android.supl.jar, ANDROID_DATA=/data, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib, ANDROID_ROOT=/system, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,65536]
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:224)
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:202)
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.logProcessResult(ActivityManagerService.java:7730)
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.access$1000(ActivityManagerService.java:205)
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$12.run(ActivityManagerService.java:8196)
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:222)
08-03 15:21:34.751: E/ActivityManager(126):  ... 4 more
08-03 15:21:34.801: W/DropBoxManagerService(126): Dropping: HTC_APP_CRASH (17488 > 16384 bytes)
```

Please help for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be that You have a very large Image for Your App Icon? something about more than 1MB?

Comment: Yes, there's an image which is pretty big, go find it, it's above 10 MB somewhere there in the folder of the application.

Comment: I don't know why you need such an image, but if it's uncompressed `bmp file` try to compress it  with `jpg` for example or `png` in order not to lose the quality.

Comment: ya got it i have the a very large icon image , I will try to test it again using small icon....Thanks